# What's wrong with my copy constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm working on implementing a Graph structure for class. In short, when attempting to compile a test program, my call to the copy constructor causes problems:

```
Graph.h: In copy constructor `Graph::Graph(Graph&) [with Object = int, Weight = int]':
gtest.cpp:16:   instantiated from here
Graph.h:129: error: base operand of `->' has non-pointer type `Graph'
gtest.cpp:16:   instantiated from here
Graph.h:131: error: base operand of `->' has non-pointer type `Graph'
```

The problematic lines are here:

```
template<typename Object,typename Weight>  //copy constructor 
Graph<Object,Weight>::Graph(Graph<Object,Weight>& G){

  for(int i=0; i<(G.edge).size(); ++i)   //129
    edge[i] = G.edge[i]; 
  for(int j=0; j<(G.vertex).size(); ++j) //131
    vertex[j] = G.vertex[j]; 

  counter = G.counter;  
}
```

...but this doesn't make sense to me, because I'm using the ".", not "->". Why would it even mention the arrow if I'm not (or at least I think I'm not) dealing with pointers?

For reference, the graph implementation I have so far is as follows (it's imcomplete; please ignore missing pieces and the /*DONE?*/ comments):

**EDIT: Before that, I'll add the gtest.cpp file where the copy constructor was called. All of the other parts work fine:

```
#include "Graph.h"

int main(){

Graph<int, int> g;


    g.insertVertex(8);
    g.insertVertex(256);
    g.insertVertex(32);
    g.insertVertex(7);
    g.insertEdge((g.vertices())[0], (g.vertices())[1], 457);
    g.insertEdge((g.vertices())[2], (g.vertices())[1], 457);
    g.insertEdge((g.vertices())[1], (g.vertices())[3], 457);

    Graph<int, int> g2 = g;

    g.print();
    }




#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H

#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <limits.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

template<typename Object,typename Weight>
class Graph{
  public:

  class Vertex;

  class Edge{
public:
    Edge(Vertex* v,Vertex* w,Weight setweight){
      start = v;
      end = w;
      v->edge.push_back(this);
      w->inedge.push_back(this);
      weight = setweight;
      explored = false;
    }
    Edge(){
      explored = false;
    }

        Weight weight;
        Vertex* start;
        Vertex* end;
        bool explored;
      };

      class Vertex{
    public:
        Vertex(Object setelement){
          level = 0;
          connectedcomponent = 0;
          element = setelement;
          back = NULL;
          explored = false;
        }
        Vertex(){
          level = 0;
          connectedcomponent = 0;
          back = NULL;
          explored = false;
        }
        Object element;
        vector<Edge*> edge;
        vector<Edge*> inedge;
        double value;
        unsigned int starttime, finishtime;
        unsigned int level;
        unsigned int connectedcomponent;
        float rank;
        Vertex* back;
      int color;
        bool explored;
      };    

      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  private:

      vector<Edge*> edge;

      vector<Vertex*> vertex;

      unsigned int counter;

  public:
      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      Graph();

      Graph(Graph& G);

      ~Graph();

      void reset();
      void resetBack();
      void resetValues();
      void resetLevels();
      void resetExplored();
      void resetConnectedComponents();

      vector<Vertex*> incidentVertices(Vertex* v);
      vector<Edge*> incidentEdges(Vertex* v);
      vector<Edge*> outgoingEdges(Vertex* v);
      vector<Vertex*> adjacentVertices(Vertex* v);
      unsigned int indegree(Vertex* v);
      unsigned int outdegree(Vertex* v);
      unsigned int degree(Vertex* v);
      Vertex* startVertex(Edge* e);
      Vertex* endVertex(Edge* e);
      // is there an edge from v to w ?
      bool isAdjacent(Vertex* v,Vertex* w);

      Vertex* insertVertex(Object o);
      void insertEdge(Vertex* v,Vertex* w,Weight t);
      void insertUndirectedEdge(Vertex* v,Vertex* w,Weight t);
      void removeVertex(Vertex* v);
      void removeEdge(Edge* e);

      unsigned int numVertices();
      unsigned int numEdges();
      vector<Vertex*> vertices();
      vector<Edge*> edges();

      void print();
      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

};



/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
Graph<Object,Weight>::Graph() :edge(0), vertex(0), counter(0) {}


/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>  //copy constructor 
Graph<Object,Weight>::Graph(Graph<Object,Weight>& G){

  for(int i=0; i<(G.edge).size(); ++i)
//    edge[i] = G.edge[i]; 
  for(int j=0; j<(G.vertex).size(); ++j)
  //  vertex[j] = G.vertex[j]; 

  counter = G.counter;  
}

/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight> //destrutor 
Graph<Object,Weight>::~Graph(){}  

/*DONE*/template<typename Object,typename Weight> 
void Graph<Object,Weight>::reset(){
  counter = 0;
  resetBack();
  resetValues();
  resetLevels();
  resetExplored();
  resetConnectedComponents();
}

/*DONE*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
void Graph<Object,Weight>::resetBack(){
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<vertex.size();i++)
      vertex[i]->back = NULL;
}

/*DONE*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
void Graph<Object,Weight>::resetValues(){
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<vertex.size();i++)
      vertex[i]->value = INT_MAX;
}

/*DONE*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
void Graph<Object,Weight>::resetLevels(){
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<vertex.size();i++)
      vertex[i]->level = 0;
}

/*DONE*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
void Graph<Object,Weight>::resetExplored(){
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<vertex.size();i++)
      vertex[i]->explored = false;
}

/*DONE*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
void Graph<Object,Weight>::resetConnectedComponents(){
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<vertex.size();i++)
      vertex[i]->connectedcomponent = 0;
}

/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>  //concatenate incoming and outgoing edge lists and return vector of total inc. edges 
vector<typename Graph<Object,Weight>::Edge*> Graph<Object,Weight>::incidentEdges(Vertex* v){
    (v->edge).insert((v->edge).end(), (v->inedge).begin(), (v->inedge).end()); 
    return v->edge; 
}

/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight> //return vector of outgoing edges
vector<typename Graph<Object,Weight>::Edge*> Graph<Object,Weight>::outgoingEdges(Vertex* v){
    return v->edge; 
}

/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
vector<typename Graph<Object,Weight>::Vertex*> Graph<Object,Weight>::incidentVertices(Vertex* v){
  vector<Vertex*> result;
  for(int i=0; i<(v->incidentEdges()).size(); ++i){
    if((v->incidentEdges())[i].endVertex() == v) result.push_back((v->incidentEdges())[i].startVertex());
      else result.push_back((v->incidentEdges())[i].endVertex()); //edges incident on vertex could be either direction    
  } 
  return result;
}

/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
vector<typename Graph<Object,Weight>::Vertex*> Graph<Object,Weight>::adjacentVertices(Vertex* v){
  vector<Vertex*> result;
  for(int i=0; i<(v->incidentEdges()).size(); ++i){
    if((v->incidentEdges())[i].startVertex() == v) result.push_back((v->incidentEdges())[i].endVertex()); } 
  return result;
}

/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
unsigned int Graph<Object,Weight>::outdegree(Vertex* v){
  return (v->adjacentVertices()).size();    
}

/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
unsigned int Graph<Object,Weight>::indegree(Vertex* v){
  return ((v->incidentEdges()).size()) - ((v->adjacentVertices()).size()); //I <3 parentheses 
}

/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
unsigned int Graph<Object,Weight>::degree(Vertex* v){
  return (v->incidentEdges()).size();    
}

/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
typename Graph<Object,Weight>::Vertex* Graph<Object,Weight>::startVertex(Edge* e){
    return e->start;    
}

/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
typename Graph<Object,Weight>::Vertex* Graph<Object,Weight>::endVertex(Edge* e){
    return e->end;    
}

// is there an edge from v to w ?
/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
bool Graph<Object,Weight>::isAdjacent(Vertex* v,Vertex* w){
  if(degree(v) <= degree(w)){ /*look in smaller incidence collection...but must fulfill directional requirements*/ 
    for(int i=0; i<(v->adjacentVertices()).size(); ++i) /*if directed edge is v to w, just check for adjacent vertex w*/ 
      if((v->adjacentVertices())[i] == w) return true; 
        else return false; }

  else{ /* if deg(w) < deg(v), look in w's incidence (not adjacency!) collection instead*/ 
    for(int i=0; i<(w->incidentEdges()).size(); ++i){ 
      if((w->incidentEdges())[i]->endVertex() == w) return true; /*badass-n. a person who keeps track of parentheses
                                  *like these and programs entirely in PuTTY
                                  *synonym: person too stubborn to take 5 minutes 
                                  *and learn Visual Studio*/  
        else return false; } 
  } 
}

/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
typename Graph<Object,Weight>::Vertex* Graph<Object,Weight>::insertVertex(Object o){
  Vertex* v = new Vertex(o); 
  vertex.push_back(v); /*construct vertex and add it to Graph's vertex vector member*/ 
}

/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
void Graph<Object,Weight>::insertEdge(Vertex* v,Vertex* w,Weight t){
  Edge* e = new Edge(v, w, t); 
  edge.push_back(e);  
}

/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
void Graph<Object,Weight>::removeEdge(Edge* e){
  edge.erase(std::find(edge.begin(), edge.end(), e)); /*remove it from overall Graph's edge vector*/  
  ((edge.end()).incidentEdges()).erase(std::find(((edge.end()).incidentEdges()).begin(), ((edge.end()).incidentEdges()).end(), e)); 
    /*...also from end vertex's incidence list...in the least confusing code possible, of course...*/
  ((edge.begin()).incidentEdges()).erase(std::find(((edge.begin()).incidentEdges()).begin(), ((edge.begin()).incidentEdges()).end(), e));
      /*...and, finally, from begin vertex's incidence list*/ 
}

template<typename Object,typename Weight>
void Graph<Object,Weight>::insertUndirectedEdge(Vertex* v,Vertex* w,Weight t){
  Edge* dir1 = new Edge(v,w,t); 
  edge.push_back(dir1); //Hmm...should I push back one or both? This thing messes up the counts!
  Edge* dir2 = newEdge(w,v,t);
  edge.push_back(dir2);  
}

/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
void Graph<Object,Weight>::removeVertex(Vertex* v){
  vertex.erase(std::find(vertex.begin(), vertex.end(), v)); /*remove it from overall Graph's vertex vector*/ 
  for(int i=0; i<(v->incidentEdges()).size(); ++i){
    if((v->incidentEdges())[i].start == v)
      (v->incidentEdges())[i].start = NULL; 
    else if((v->incidentEdges())[i].end == v)
      (v->incidentEdges())[i].end = NULL; }  
}

/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
unsigned int Graph<Object,Weight>::numVertices(){
  return vertex.size(); 
}

/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
unsigned int Graph<Object,Weight>::numEdges(){
  return edge.size(); 
}

/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
vector<typename Graph<Object,Weight>::Vertex* > Graph<Object,Weight>::vertices(){
  return vertex; 
}

/*DONE?*/template<typename Object,typename Weight>
vector<typename Graph<Object,Weight>::Edge* > Graph<Object,Weight>::edges(){
  return edge; 
}

template<typename Object,typename Weight>
void Graph<Object,Weight>::print(){
  cout << "vertices:" << endl;
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<vertex.size();i++)
      cout << vertex[i]->element << endl;
      cout << "edges:" << endl;
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<edge.size();i++)
      cout << "(" << edge[i]->start->element << "," << edge[i]->end->element << ")" << endl;
}

#endif
```

Comment: `Graph(Graph& G);` should be `Graph(const Graph& G);`

Comment: Not sure as to the reported problem, but the vector<> default copy should work fine anyway. Well, no worse than your proposal I mean: you need to manage memory somehow.

Comment: Show gtest.cpp line 16. And yes, it is much safer to get familiar with using *const*.

Comment: Hmm I don't see any error in the code you pasted: http://ideone.com/ezeF0

Comment: That code compiles just fine with Clang (2.9) and gcc (4.6.1).

Comment: Verify here: http://ideone.com/rM1aC

Comment: It's probably unrelated, but in `Graph::insertUndirectedEdge` is a space missing. Additionally, I'd recommend to use smart pointers to be safe in case of an exception. I'm already missing corresponding deletes in `removeEdge`, but I might have overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

Please do check again where the problem appears. Something like,

```
template <typename T, typename K>
struct A
{
  T i;
  A(){};
  A(A&);
};

template <typename T, typename K>
A<T,K>::A(A<T,K>& that)
{
  i=that.i;
}

int main()
{
  A<int,int> _a;
  A<int,int> _b(_a);
  return 0;
}
```

is standard, and compiles OK.

Comment: @user1343118 : Your code (with EDIT) simply compiles without any problems (I have checked it now with gcc-4.0.1, and 4.6.1). You might put the `main()` behind the whole class in one file and compile. It should be OK. If you still get errors, then please give details of the environment under which you are compiling.

Answer (score 0):

The error probably lies in gtest.cpp line 16, which is invoked in the Graph.h :129 and :131. Have a look there.

Maybe the size() function has a problem?

Answer (score 0):

WOW. Just wow.

As it turns out, there were TWO identically-named "Graph.h" files in my directory. Of course, one was old and had the '->' mistake. I got rid of it (how it even got there I do not know), and now everything runs fine.

Thanks for all of the help, everyone!

P.S.--does anyone think it would be advantageous to accommodate the "insertUndirectedEdge" function by simply adding an "undirected edge" member to the entire data structure? The implementation framework was basically given to us without that, and the instructor said that we would need to use two edges (u-v and v-u) to make an undirected one between two vertices u and v. Maybe I'm missing something, but this seems like it would be more trouble than it's worth, especially considering the counts (no. of incident edges on a vertex, etc.) that it would complicate.